# How to Select ringtone from ringtonePicker dialog and show it in a textview when i press OK

Tags: android

[image: here is the image]

How to Select ringtone from ringtonePicker dialog and show it in a textview when i press OK and how to set the default checkbox to 'Default ringtone';currently it is in 'Andromeda'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i did it, just replace ringtone type for type You need.
Show dialog:

```
private void getNotificationSound() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "Select Alert Tone");
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, (Uri) null);
        this.startActivityForResult(intent, 8);
    }
```

Get user selection:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent intent) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 8) {
            Uri uri = intent.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
            if (uri != null) {

                Log.d(TAG, uri.toString());
                Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, uri);
                String title = ringtone.getTitle(this);
                tvSoundName.setText("Alert Sound: " + title);
            }
        }
    }
```